# Why isn't $_SESSION data being passed to all parts of my function file?

Tags: php, class, session-variables

I am reworking a lot of login scripts and ran across one of our internal sites with a large function file set up like this.

- CLASS

  - Function
  - Function
- CLASS...
- CLASS
- CLASS validate user
- CLASS
- CLASS

I have a script that I run that retrieves the SSO `$_SESSION` data and would like to pass it on from SSO server to the user's session.

I have tried running the script in different parts of the file but get the same result.   It works in some places and not others.

I can echo out all of the `$_SESSION` variables to an HTML page.

I can also use the `$_SESSION` data in SOME classes (always the same no matter where I put it).

However the class I really need to use it - validate user - everything comes up null.

Am I missing something here (please don't tell me to put a `session_start();` in).

I thought `$_SESSION` data was superglobal. Is retrieved `$_SESSION` data superglobal too?

If not what do I need to do to make it superglobal?

Here is the script I use to retrieve session data to pass on -

```
session_start(); 
$appKey = "00000000Uz";
$safeurl =  'https://safe.000000.com/login/sso/SSOService?app=playbooks';
// first call back after safe login - POST is set
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['digest'])) 
{
    $digest = $_POST["digest"];

    // set the session variables ...
    $_SESSION['usernames'] = $_POST["firstname"]." ".$_POST["lastname"];
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST["firstname"];
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST["lastname"];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST["email"];
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST["uid"];

    // Needed for key
    $uid = $_POST["uid"];
    $time = $_POST["time"];

    // Read the property file with the key and URL so this won't go into the main code 
    // this sets $appKey and $safeurl
    $mykey = "".$uid.$time.$appKey;
    $mydigest = md5($mykey);
}

// session is not initialized as we never got the post above to set session vars
// call now the safe login to get the post to set the session vars ...
if (!isset($_SESSION['uid']) || empty($_SESSION['uid']))
{
    // Read the property file with the key and URL so this won't go into the main code 
    // this sets $appKey and $safeurl
    header("Location: ".$safeurl);
}          

$usr = $_SESSION['uid'];         
$this->setCurrentUserName($usr);
return TRUE;      
}
```

Comment: The $_SESSION is a global array always. If you don't see the value in some places, it most likely you deleted them before. Obviously be insure to run session_start if it doesn't run automatically with PHP ini settings.

Comment: `$_SESSION` is a global variable, it's is always available (after calling `session_start()`). That being said, relying on globals is bad, it makes for unmaintainable code. Make one class that deals with raw sessions.

Comment: Are you calling session start before running the portion of the script that populates the $_SESSION variable? If it is in the place you have it in your question, you would likely be retrieving data before starting the session, which will not populate $_SESSION. Also, where is this code that you've placed in your question? In one of the classes?

Comment: Is session_start() in the wrong place in my code in the question?  Right now the script is at the very top of the php page... All of the session variables can be echoed but they do not work in some of the classes period.  Some they do.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are calling `session_start()` prior to using `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Is session_start() in the wrong place in my code in the question?  Right now the script is at the very top of the php page... All of the session variables can be echoed but they do not work in some of the classes period.  Some they do.

Comment: `header("Location: ".$safeurl);` - whatever file this is, you'll need to run `session_start()` as well. Only the parent (caller) file needs it. All included files will be able to use `$_SESSION`. You could be safe and do `if(session_id() == '') session_start();` in all your files...

Comment: I have if(session_id() == '') session_start(); in all files.  However I cannot add it to $safeurl because that is the SSO server the session details.  All of my session data works it just cannot be referenced in a couple classes in this one file... driving me nuts really because I thought this was a 20 min implementation.

Comment: Sessions only work on the server you're using them on.. you can't (easily) pass session data from server1 to server2.. is this what you mean?

Comment: Actually, wait.. this php file is the callback for your SSO test, right? If so, then it's probably POSTING data - not using sessions. Check `die(var_dump($_POST))` in your PHP page to see what's going on...

Comment: The SSO is posting data.  The file I have in my question takes the post data and assigns SESSION data to it.  Am I doing that wrong?

Comment: Before you `return true`, run a `die(var_dump($_SESSION))`. See anything? If so, then your sessions are working fine. If not, then your logic in the conditions are flawed. Also, where are you `return true`ing to? Another file on the same server I assume?

Comment: I did a variable dump at a few spots and everything is getting passed in those spots.  It must be something wrong with the login script he wrote.  What is really odd is that I go to page - I can see my username - but no credentials passed - I then add the die comment in code - I see all of my session variables - take out the die comment - bam my user is passed with all of the attributes and credentials.